# запись в файл в языке си

Tags: c, файлы, форматирование

Что делают эти части кода:

1)

```
fprintf( asf , "\xd\xa\xd\xa" );
```

2)

```
fprintf( asf , "x[" "%u" "] = " "%f" \xd\xa" , i+1 , *( x + i ) );
```

А точнее вот эти символы \xd\xa

Answer (score 3):

Шестнадцатеричное представление символов.

Фактически `\xd\xa` - то же самое, что `\r\n`.

Comment: типо как endl в c++?

Comment: и еще вопрос можно же заменить "x[" "%u" "] = " "%f" \xd\xa" на "x[ %u ] = %f \xd\xa" или нет?

Comment: `\x##` представляет собой запись символа с номером `##` в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления - как `\0###` - запись символа с номером `###` в восьмеричной системе счисления. С `endl` - ничего общего. Записанные подряд строковые литералы конкатенируются, т.е. `"string1" "string2"` - то же самое, что и `"string1string2"`.

Comment: Там какая-то беда с кавычками, лучше так: `"x[%u] = %f\r\n"`